# Slide down and slide up reverse

Tags: jquery

When hovering over div, second div slides down, and when not hovering slides back up. I am having issues in doing it the other way. Is there a way of making the div slide up on hover, and slide back down when not hovering? So essentially, it slides up into the hovering div

```js
function animationRollover(element, rollover) {
  $(element).hover(function() {
    $(rollover).slideDown();
  }, function() {
    $(rollover).slideUp();
  });
};
animationRollover('#divImage1', '#divTextImage1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divImage1" style="float: left; width: 280px; margin-left: 40px; border: 1px solid">
  <div style="height: 50px;">
    test
  </div>
  <div id="divTextImage1" style="width: 280px; height: 20px; background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.6 ); float: left; position: absolute; opacity: 0.5; color: white; display: none;">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `display: none;` from `<div id='divTextImage1'" ..>` style attribute and invert `slideUp` with `slideDown`.

```js
function animationRollover(element, rollover) {
  $(element).hover(function() {
    $(rollover).slideUp();
  }, function() {
    $(rollover).slideDown();
  });
};
animationRollover('#divImage1', '#divTextImage1');
```

```css
#divImage1 {
  position: relative;
}

#divTextImage1 {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="divImage1" style="float: left; width: 280px; margin-left: 40px; border: 1px solid">
  <div style="height: 50px;">
   test image
   <div id="divTextImage1" style="width: 280px; height: 20px; background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.6 ); float: left; position: absolute; opacity: 0.5; color: white;">
    test text
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, essentially like that. But instead of it being outside the blackbox i am trying to get it inside the black box

Comment: @p.developer Edited answer, like that?